# How do I use streams/filters/lambdas from an iterator and for loop?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm not too familiar with streams, filters, and lambdas as I'm used to writing older Java code. I wanted to try using new things in newer versions of Java. I can't seem to get anything started without getting compiling problems. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
List<Obj> a = getListForA();    // ['werdsegs', 'wsghnmrst', 'vaasdfdas', 'iujhgfds']
List<Obj> b = getListForB();    // ['aalaksdjf', 'erftghjuk', 'werdsejfksd', 'asdklgjaklgj', 'poijgndf']

a.forEach((item) -> {
    String foo = item.substring(0,5);
    for(Iterator<Obj> i = b.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Obj o = i.next();
        if(foo.equals(o.substring(0,5)) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
});
```

I expect for any item that contains the substring, remove it from the list for b.

After the code runs, list b should show the list below with `werdsejfksd` missing from
`['aalaksdjf', 'erftghjuk', 'asdklgjaklgj', 'poijgndf']`

Comment: `foo.equals(o.substring(0,5))` will never be true, what with `foo` being 11 characters long, and `o.substring(0, 5)` being 5 character long.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use item not 'hello world' as foo

Comment: "_I can't seem to get anything started without getting compiling problems_" If it doesn't compile, tell us the error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Why is `Obj` not `String`.. There is so much I don't get about this question. Would you mind posting a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: That code runs fine, assuming you replace `Obj` with `String` and fix the compilation errors.

Comment: You have a misspelling: Iterator<Ojb> --> Iterator<Obj>, but I doubt this is the problem you are looking for.

Comment: I initially tried to starrt with something like `a.stream().filter(stuff_here)` but I couldn't really understand how to start it out so it became evident there'd be compiling issues. I'm not sure that's even the way to go about it

Comment: I used obj in this example to be generic about the question so anyone else who had similar issues could replace it with their own values

Comment: @user2624768 if you want to make it "generic", use a `BiPredicate<Obj, String>` to identify items to remove.

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs fine if you replace `Obj` with `String` and fix the compilation errors:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("werdsegs", "wsghnmrst", "vaasdfdas", "iujhgfds");
List<String> b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("aalaksdjf", "erftghjuk", "werdsejfksd", "asdklgjaklgj", "poijgndf"));

a.forEach((item) -> {
    String foo = item.substring(0,5);
    for (Iterator<String> i = b.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        String o = i.next();
        if (foo.equals(o.substring(0,5))) {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
});

System.out.println(b); // prints: [aalaksdjf, erftghjuk, asdklgjaklgj, poijgndf]
```

As suggested by jonathan Heindl in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55482662/5221149), you can simplify the code by using [`removeIf(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-). I'd build a `Set` first, though, for better performance:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("werdsegs", "wsghnmrst", "vaasdfdas", "iujhgfds");
List<String> b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("aalaksdjf", "erftghjuk", "werdsejfksd", "asdklgjaklgj", "poijgndf"));

Set<String> set = a.stream().map(s -> s.substring(0,5)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
b.removeIf(s -> set.contains(s.substring(0,5)));

System.out.println(b); // prints: [aalaksdjf, erftghjuk, asdklgjaklgj, poijgndf]
```

If you want a new list, instead of modifying `b`, you can use the `filter(...)` method of `Stream`:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("werdsegs", "wsghnmrst", "vaasdfdas", "iujhgfds");
List<String> b = Arrays.asList("aalaksdjf", "erftghjuk", "werdsejfksd", "asdklgjaklgj", "poijgndf");

Set<String> set = a.stream().map(s -> s.substring(0,5)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
List<String> c = b.stream().filter(s -> ! set.contains(s.substring(0,5))).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(c); // prints: [aalaksdjf, erftghjuk, asdklgjaklgj, poijgndf]
```

Comment: Looks excellent, but can you explain how you got to this? I'm trying to understand which part you looked at my code and then changed it to as shown. I don't really understand how stream, filter and lambda exactly works

Comment: @user2624768 The first block *is* your code, how can you not compare and see what little I changed? Sure, I replaced `getListForA()` with a call to `Arrays.asList` to make the code a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but that should be obvious.

Answer (score -1):

I guess like this

```
List<String> a = getListForA();    // ['werdsegs', 'wsghnmrst', 'vaasdfdas', 'iujhgfds']
List<String> b = getListForB();    // ['aalaksdjf', 'erftghjuk', 'werdsejfksd', 'asdklgjaklgj', 'poijgndf']

b.removeIf(bObj->a.stream().anyMatch(aObj->aObj.substring(0,5).equals(bObj.substring(0,5))));
```

Comment: Looks excellent, but can you explain how you got to this? I'm trying to understand which part you looked at my code and then changed it to as shown. I don't really understand how your stream and lambda came to be

Comment: well the first b.removeIf is a plain List function (like the name implies) it removes elements if the lambda function you pass it returns true (it also passes along the iterating object here as bObj) 

so now we need a function that iterates over the a arrays and returns true if the  evaluated strings match for this we have the stream function anyMatch which returns true if any of the passed lambda functions returns true but since its a stream function we need to convertz the list to a stream which .stream is for 

next we pass it the lamda predicate to compare the strings and were done(y)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. That really helped me understand the streaming part and where the lambdas come in

Comment: Answers only containing code without any explanation are not considered good answers here at SO but since I see you have written a lengthy comment maybe you can improve your answer by adding the content of your comment to your answer